# how can I get all_trades_total_profit in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get values from an array using map I am trying to calculate total profit but all_trades_total_profit is only providing me just value of first profit not adding up to total to show all sum.

and also all_trades_total_profit is declared globally in component as default value 0

```
<Table variant="simple">
                <Thead>
                  <Tr>
                    <Th>Asset</Th>
                    <Th>Buy Price</Th>
                    <Th >Sell Price</Th>
                    <Th>Profit</Th>
                    <Th>Buying Date</Th>
                    <Th >Selling Date</Th>
                    <Th >Total Buy</Th>
                    <Th>Expected Selling Price</Th>
                    <Th>Expected Profit</Th>

                  </Tr>
                </Thead>
                <Tbody>
                  {
                    all_trades.trades.map((trade) => {
                      const profit = (((trade.total_buy / trade.buying_price) * trade.selling_price) - trade.total_buy).toFixed(3);
                      all_trades_total_profit = all_trades_total_profit+ profit;
                      return (
                        <Tr backgroundColor={trade.is_open ? "green.200" : ""} key={trade.trade_id}>
                          <Td>{trade.asset_name}</Td>
                          <Td>{(trade.buying_price).toFixed(3)}</Td>
                          <Td >{(trade.selling_price).toFixed(3)}</Td>


                          <Td width="5" margin="10" backgroundColor={profit > 0 ? "green.100" : "red"} >{profit}</Td>
                          <Td>{trade.buying_date}</Td>
                          <Td >{trade.selling_date}</Td>
                          <Td >{trade.total_buy}</Td>
                          <Td>{trade.expected_selling_price}</Td>
                          <Td>{trade.expected_profit}</Td>
                          <Td d="flex"> <Button mr="5" onClick={() => editTrade(trade)}>Edit</Button>
                            <Button onClick={() => deleteTrade(trade)}>Delete</Button> </Td>
                        </Tr>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </Tbody>
                <Tfoot>

                  <Tr>
                    <Th>Total</Th>
                    <Th>{parseFloat(all_trades_total_profit).toFixed(3)}</Th>
                  </Tr>


                </Tfoot>
              </Table>
```

Comment: because the state is not changed (which requires setState() ). So first time whatever values it get it prints it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, putting an answer it might help someone.

what I did is actually made a function which returns the total value. and show that total value there by calling that function.

here is simple function code.

```
  const calculateOpenTradesTotalProfit = () => {

let total_profit = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < all_trades.trades.length; i++) {
  if (all_trades.trades[i].is_open) {
    total_profit += (((all_trades.trades[i].total_buy / all_trades.trades[i].buying_price) * all_trades.trades[i].selling_price) - all_trades.trades[i].total_buy)
  }
}
return total_profit;
```

}